# How can I find the PhD thesis of C.A. Ellis?

Tags: reference-request, probabilistic-automata

I've searched for this article all over the web but couldn't find it. can anyone help me?

Ellis, C.A. 1969. Probabilistic languages and automata. Rept. no. 355. Dept. Comp.
Sc. University of Illinois, Urbana, Ill.
PhD Thesis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find a pdf with the thesis in the following way:

1. Find the wikipedia page for Clarence Ellis;
2. On the wikipedia page find the link to his thesis "Probabilistic languages and automata";
3. Click on this link to find the corresponding archive.org page;
4. Download the thesis at archive.org.